# how to add time limit condition to PHP echo

Tags: php

i have this php code

```
}else{
                echo apply_filters('wplms_start_quiz_button','<a class="button create-group-button full begin_quiz" data-quiz="'.get_the_ID().'"> '.__('Start Quiz','vibe').'</a>',get_the_ID());
                 wp_nonce_field('start_quiz','start_quiz');
            }
```

### i want to add an if condition to this code like code below:

```
    }else{
```

if it's Thursday or Friday then==>

```
echo apply_filters('wplms_start_quiz_button','<a class="button create-group-button full begin_quiz" data-quiz="'.get_the_ID().'"> '.__('Start Quiz','vibe').'</a>',get_the_ID());
                     wp_nonce_field('start_quiz','start_quiz');
                }
```

and if its Saturday to Wednesday then ==>

```
echo "some string";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime. Format N for day of the week like this:

```
if(in_array((new DateTime)->format('N'),[3,4])) {   
  .... your code on thursday or friday 
} else {
  ....
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php